# Shutdown PowerShell GUI is clunky to drag around or click the Cancel button whilst counting down

Tags: powershell, user-interface, window

Hello PoSh Gurus and learned folk;  I've recently created a simple shutdown GUI to use that counts down 30 minutes prior to shutting down a machine.  It works well however I am looking for ways to increase the performance of the script.

**Issue:**
Whilst the counter ticks down, the label that shows the countdown ticks works OK.  When I attempt to move the window however, there's a delay in dragging the window and when I click Cancel, there's almost a 1 second delay from when I hit cancel to when the form shuts down. Any ideas on how to tweak the code or even scrap the code completely and work from scratch would be very well received :)

Many thanks for your help!

```
function GenerateForm {   
#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$frmShutdown = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$grpBody = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$lblCounter = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblShutdowntime = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblMessage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$btnCancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$lblTitle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$btnCancel_OnClick= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here
   [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
   $btnCancel.Enabled = $false
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $frmShutdown.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$OnLoadForm_LoadControls=
{
    [int]$s = 59
    [int]$m = 29
    $script:CancelLoop = $false
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
    Do
    {        
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        $lblCounter.Text = "$m minutes $s seconds"
        Sleep -seconds 1
        if($s -lt 1){$m--;$s=60}
        If($btnCancel.Enabled -eq $false)
        {
            $cancel = $true
            break            
        }
        $s--
    }While(($m -ge 0))
    If(!($cancel)){Stop-Computer}
    $frmShutdown.Close()    
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 269
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 536
$frmShutdown.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$frmShutdown.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$frmShutdown.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",18,0,3,1)
$frmShutdown.FormBorderStyle = 5
$frmShutdown.Name = "frmShutdown"
$frmShutdown.Text = "SHUTDOWN IN PROGRESS"


$grpBody.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 25
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 45
$grpBody.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$grpBody.Name = "grpBody"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 145
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 499
$grpBody.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$grpBody.TabIndex = 3
$grpBody.TabStop = $False

$frmShutdown.Controls.Add($grpBody)
$lblCounter.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$lblCounter.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",15.75,0,3,1)
$lblCounter.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,0,0)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 222
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 106
$lblCounter.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$lblCounter.Name = "lblCounter"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 29
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 236
$lblCounter.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$lblCounter.TabIndex = 4
$lblCounter.Text = ""

$grpBody.Controls.Add($lblCounter)

$lblShutdowntime.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$lblShutdowntime.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14.25,0,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 22
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 107
$lblShutdowntime.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$lblShutdowntime.Name = "lblShutdowntime"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 26
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 194
$lblShutdowntime.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$lblShutdowntime.TabIndex = 3
$lblShutdowntime.Text = "Shutdown will start in: 30 minutes 00 seconds"

$grpBody.Controls.Add($lblShutdowntime)

$lblMessage.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$lblMessage.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",11.25,0,3,1)
$lblMessage.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 22
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 21
$lblMessage.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$lblMessage.Name = "lblMessage"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 73
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 463
$lblMessage.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$lblMessage.TabIndex = 2
$lblMessage.Text = "This computer is going to be shut down.  If you are using this computer and wish to abort the shutdown, please click Cancel below."
$lblMessage.TextAlign = 32

$grpBody.Controls.Add($lblMessage)



$btnCancel.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 208
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 199
$btnCancel.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 58
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 146
$btnCancel.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btnCancel.TabIndex = 1
$btnCancel.Text = "CANCEL"
$btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnCancel.Add_Click($btnCancel_OnClick)
#$btnCancel.add_Click($btnCancel_OnClick)

$frmShutdown.Controls.Add($btnCancel)

$lblTitle.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$lblTitle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",18,1,3,1)
$lblTitle.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,0,0)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 47
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 9
$lblTitle.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$lblTitle.Name = "lblTitle"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 40
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 447
$lblTitle.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$lblTitle.TabIndex = 0
$lblTitle.Text = "SYSTEM SHUTDOWN SCHEDULED"

$frmShutdown.Controls.Add($lblTitle)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $frmShutdown.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$frmShutdown.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
$frmShutdown.TopMost = $True
$frmShutdown.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$frmShutdown.ControlBox = $False
$frmShutdown.MaximizeBox = $False
$frmShutdown.add_Load($OnLoadForm_LoadControls)

#$frmShutdown.Modal = system
#Show the Form
$frmShutdown.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing those lags due to the `Sleep` in your loop.

Try using a timer instead. The timer will be called by Windows at a given interval and will nicely execute your commands in the background. Actions on the user interface will not be disrupted by the timer.

So lets create a timer.

Some cleanup first.

Remove your `$OnLoadForm_LoadControl` script block. You won't need it. 
Remove also

```
$frmShutdown.add_Load($OnLoadForm_LoadControls)
```

You won't need it.

Place the following in your script:

```
$global:s = 59
$global:m = 1
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000


$action = {
    $lblCounter.Text = "$global:m minutes $s seconds"
    if($s -lt 1){$global:m--;$global:s=60}
    If($btnCancel.Enabled -eq $false)
    {
        $cancel = $true      
    }
    $global:s--

    if ($global:m -eq 0 -and $global:s -eq 0)
    {
        #If(!($cancel)){Stop-Computer}
        $timer.Enabled = $false
        $frmShutdown.Close()    

    }

}
$timer.add_tick($action)
```

OK this creates a WinForm timer and does not start it yet.

Note that Stop-Computer is commented out, as you should try this before performing that command.
Also note that $global:m is set to 1 min, you will need to changed it 29 minutes.

Right before `$frmShutdown.ShowDialog()| Out-Null` at the bottom of your script add:

```
$timer.Start()
```

The timer will start, and your message tag should be updating. 
You can click Cancel or move your window without lags.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear and concise response Micky!  I will try out in the AM :) . Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: The solution above has resolved the issue, thank you!